# I'm getting the same image from album even after cleaning camera cache

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I`m building cordova android project. The problem is to add a picture via cordova camera plugin. All goes fine exept when I try to remove current image with new one.

Always getting the first image. I tried clearing camera cache and changing img property with some random numbers. That didn`t help. What can be done else?

```js
$(document).on('touchstart', '#takePic', function () {
    navigator.camera.cleanup();
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccessC, onFail, {
        quality: 70,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
        correctOrientation: true,
        allowEdit: true
    });
    $("#takePic").toggle();
});

function onSuccessC(imageURI) {
    var image = document.getElementById('largeImage');
    image.src = imageURI;
    alert(image.src);
    $("#largeImage").show();
}

$(document).on('touchstart', '#largeImage', function () {
    $("#largeImage").prop("src", "img/logo.png" + '?' + Math.random());
    $("#largeImage").hide();
    $("#takePic").toggle();
});

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#add-vendor', function () {
    $("#largeImage").hide();
});
```

```html
<div id="takePic" class="ui-btn ui-icon-camera ui-btn-icon-notext"></div>
<img id="largeImage" src="" width="120" hspace="20" vspace="20" />
```

Cant give a working example so that it wont work without cordova.js file.

**EDIT**

First self-made investigation results. If I turn off edit feature, hte image uri will look like ..../cache/modified.jpg?1417011797953 which is obviously mean that caching works. And All waorks fine by the way.

If I turn edit feature on, I got image uri like this .../chache/.pic.jpg which is at first glance lack caching... will see further into it.

Comment: Are you trying to select existing photo from the device or capture a new photo and use it?

Comment: I use sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM that is meant that I`m choosing an existed file. The same heppens with PHOTOLIBRARY as a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further investigation showed that there was a bug in plugin. Caching was not working when edit feature was enabled. To fix, I just add some randoms.

```
function onSuccess(imageURI) {
var image = document.getElementById('largeImage');
image.src = imageURI + '?' + Math.random();
alert(image.src);
$("#largeImage").show();
}
```

Have a good day.

Comment: I've to use this workaround on iOS too after having introduced the call to cordova.camera.cleanup()

Answer (score 1):

**Its not a Plugin issue.**

There is some internal **WebView cache** issue as it has already happened to other people. read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713833/clear-uiwebview-cache-when-use-local-image-file) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361312/ios-cordova-camera-plugin-referring-to-deleted-images).

Yes, up to this time the solution is to append time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is already adding the current timestamp to make the cached filename (your actually editing the image by getting a variant with 70% quality, so that needs to be cached) unique and prevent the trouble you are experiencing (see [this github code line of the plugin repo)](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/src/android/CameraLauncher.java#L552).

I suggest you use console.log to print the imageURI to your debugger and check if the same URI is used multiple times somehow.

Comment: Thank you for you help in investigating. I figured that caching was off when edit feature turn on. Plugin bug. See the proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/doc/index.md#description-1, `cleanup` works only when the value of `Camera.sourceType` equals `Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA` **and** the `Camera.destinationType` equals `Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI` which means it works only when you are capturing from camera and saving to device.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Cleaning was added in desperate attempt to change things. See the proper answer.