# Getting the path to the tmp folder and deleting contents on iOS phonegap/cordova

Tags: ios, file, cordova

I'm having a hard time figuring out the phonegap/codrova `file` api docs.

How does one find the path to the application's tmp folder and then list/delete the contents without deleting the folder itself?

This specifically relates to the deletion of temporary image files created when I pull a photo from the device's image gallery.

Answer (score 7):

This function uses the cordova file plugin to delete a specific file from the tmp folder

```
deleteFile: function(fileName) {

        var that = this;

        if (!fileName) {
            console.error("No fileName specified. File could not be deleted.");
            return false;
        }

        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, function(fileSystem){ // this returns the tmp folder 

            // File found
            fileSystem.root.getFile(fileName, {create: false}, function(fileEntry){
                fileEntry.remove(function(success){
                    console.log(success);
                }, function(error){
                    console.error("deletion failed: " + error);
                });
            }, that.get('fail'));
        }, this.get('fail'));

    }
```

You could tweak it a bit to find all files first and remove them. Something like this

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, function(fileSystem){ {
    var reader = fileSystem.root.createReader();
    reader.readEntries(function(entries) {

        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
            if (entries[i].name.indexOf(".png") != -1) {
               // delete stuff from above could go in here
            }
        }
    }, fail);    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the temporary images, you have the [cleanup option](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_camera_camera.cleanup.md.html#camera.cleanup)

```
navigator.camera.cleanup( cameraSuccess, cameraError );
```

Comment: This does work, however I then run into the problem outlined here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713833/clear-uiwebview-cache-when-use-local-image-file that I cannot seem to solve either. This issue is that the chosen photo isn't the one you chose after using the camera.cleanup method, it will be the most recent of the deleted images rather than the one you just selected from the camera roll.